# DB2: xmlparse/cursor no result set

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, db2

Techies--
Even though I know I have 2 rows, 1 with an EMPNO match on 000020 and another on 000030, I get an empty result set. Any ideas?

Here's the call:

```
CALL DB2INST1.EMP_MULTIPLE_XML(XMLPARSE(
    DOCUMENT '<EMPLOYEE><EMPNO>000020</EMPNO><EMPNO>000030</EMPNO></EMPLOYEE>'));
```

Here's the alterd sproc:

```
   BEGIN

   CREATE PROCEDURE DB2INST1.EMP_MULTIPLE_XML (IN DOC XML)
   DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
   READS SQL DATA
   LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC EMP_MULTIPLE_XML

   DECLARE CSR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT emp.EMPNO,
           emp.FIRSTNME,
           emp.LASTNAME,
           emp.WORKDEPT
     FROM DB2INST1.EMPLOYEE emp
     WHERE emp.EMPNO IN
      (SELECT X.EMPNO FROM
        XMLTABLE('$d/EMPLOYEE/EMPNO' PASSING DOC AS "d" COLUMNS EMPNO CHAR(6) PATH 'EMPNO') AS X);

 OPEN CSR1;
 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those following this thread behind me, here is sproc that works:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.INPUT_MULTIPLE_XML (IN DOC XML) 
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1  
  LANGUAGE SQL SPECIFIC INPUT_MULTIPLE_XML  
  BEGIN  
     DECLARE CSR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR    
        select t.type,          
               t.tabschema,          
               t.tabname    
         from syscat.tables t,      
          XMLTABLE('$d/tables/tabname' PASSING DOC AS "d" 
          COLUMNS "TABNAME" VARCHAR(128) PATH '.'    ) AS X   
           WHERE X.tabname = t.tabname ;    

  OPEN CSR1;  
  END
```

Comment: I'm going to leave this sample code in my answer, so it doesn't need to be copied to a new, separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `FETCH` doesn't appear to be necessary, considering the proc is passing the result set out of the procedure. Try removing the FETCH and everything after it (except for the final END).

The `'$d/employee'` argument in your invocation of `XMLTABLE` is incorrect because you want a row of tabular output for each occurrence of `'$d/employee/empno'`, not `'$d/employee'`. That is what's causing the error about *item(), item()+*

This proc is an independent sample that shows how to accomplish your goal of passing a set of input values through an XML document parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.INPUT_MULTIPLE_XML (IN DOC XML)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC INPUT_MULTIPLE_XML

BEGIN

DECLARE CSR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR

  select t.type,
         t.tabschema,
         t.tabname
   from syscat.tables t,  
   XMLTABLE('$d/tables/tabname' PASSING DOC AS "d" 
            COLUMNS "TABNAME" VARCHAR(128) PATH '.'
   ) AS X
   WHERE X.tabname = t.tabname
;

  OPEN CSR1;

END
```

Comment: Thanks Fred--the status comes back as successful in IBM Data Studio, but I don't see any returned data under results. Wouldn't I normally see the returned dataset in the results tab?

Comment: roughly when I execute this statement, i get back 2 rows. i am trying to replicate this resultset in the sproc/call above: select emp.empno,emp.firstname,emp.workdept from db2inst1.employee emp where emp.empno in (select x.empno from db2inst1.employee x where x.empno in ('000020','000030'));

Comment: Fred--thanks for answering this. especially for clearing up what the deal was with item()+, etc. On the bright side, no errors--but still no results.

Comment: ...now I'm thinking I've done something really stupid...casting maybe? nayy... the table definition for empno is char(6), the tags have the same values stored in empno in the employee table...I have other columns, but I only really care about a match on empno.

Comment: You're now referencing EMPNO in your row producing path at the beginning of your `XMLTABLE()` expression, which is correct, but you also left it in the relative XPath for the column, which is causing the expression to look for /EMPLOYEE/EMPNO/EMPNO. Replace the `PATH 'EMPNO'` with `PATH '.'` like in my example, and you should start getting some results.

Comment: Brilliantly done Fred! Thanks for all your help. I finally understand now what you were trying to tell me about /empno and path '.'!:-)

Comment: Glad to be of help. When you have a spare moment, please mark my answer to show that it solved your problem.